# Telerik Kendo UI Grid - Inline editing of composite object as a single column with multi-field widget

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid

We are considering kendo ui to replace GWT in our ERP product. The main motivator is kendo grid. We have many composite objects that are rendered and edited as a single column. The column editor will contain multiple fields.

An example: In sales invoice lines, the product column should display *product code (autocomplete field)*, *product name (Link)*, and a *button* to open products browser (a modal dialog with search fields and a grid that displays products along with images, names, available quantities, etc).After selecting a product in the products browser the grid should update the product in the row that requested the browser.

I think I know how to implement the products browser. But the composite editor is the one I do not know how to implement.

My question is: how can I edit a composite object in a single grid column using a composite widget? And we need inline editing not popup editors.

I have been browsing the demos to find a close example but could not find any. My search was "kendo grid composite object custom editor".

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do that with Kendo UI

Check this demo (a ComboBox with a custom template)

http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/combobox/template

You can create a custom row's template for the ComboBox (with multiple columns like in the demo) and in the grid you can use a custom template for the column *products* and use the ComboBox with the custom template.

Check this demo for the grid with a custom column template

http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/editing-custom